# Calculate average of a column when two other columns values match

Tags: python, arrays

I am looking for a simple way to iterate over a Python array and average the third column when the two first columns are identical.

For instance, this array:

```
['0.30', '1.9', 5]
['0.30', '1.9', 33]
['0.30', '1.9', 39]
['0.30', '2.0', 21]
['0.30', '2.0', 51]
['0.30', '2.0', 51]
['0.30', '2.1', 42]
['0.30', '2.1', 34]
['0.30', '2.1', 43]
['0.30', '2.2', 38]
['0.30', '2.2', 34]
['0.30', '2.2', 50]
['0.34', '1.9', 29]
['0.34', '1.9', 47]
['0.34', '2.0', 45]
['0.34', '2.0', 31]
['0.34', '2.0', 45]
['0.34', '2.0', 57]
['0.34', '2.0', 25]
```

should become:

```
['0.30', '1.9', 25.66]
['0.30', '2.0', 41.00
['0.30', '2.1', 39.66]
['0.30', '2.2', 40.66]
['0.30', '2.3', 26.00]
['0.34', '1.9', 38.00]
['0.34', '2.0', 40.60]
```

How to go about doing this in Python?

Comment: Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).  `for k, g in groupby(your_array, key=lambda x: x[:2]): ...`

Comment: Thanks so much, it works great! Can you convert your comment into an answer so I can validate it? Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

final = []
for k,v in groupby(l,lambda x:x[:2]):
    lst = list(v)
    avg = sum(x[2] for x in lst) / float(len(lst))
    lst[0][2] = round(avg,2)
    final.append(lst[0])
print final
[['0.30', '1.9', 25.67], ['0.30', '2.0', 41.0], ['0.30', '2.1', 39.67], ['0.30', '2.2', 40.67], ['0.34', '1.9', 38.0], ['0.34', '2.0', 40.6]]
```

If you are using python 3.4 you can use the statistics lib to calculate the mean:

```
from statistics import mean

avg = mean(x[2] for x in lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

An obvious solution is to use hashing. I would create a `dictionary` with a `tuple` of the first 2 columns as the key and the value being a list of numbers corresponding to that pair.

Here's some code to illustrate:

```
data = {}
for item in array:
    data.setdefault((item[0], item[1]), []).append(item[2])

for k, v in d.items():
    print k, sum(v)/len(v)
```

Result:

```
('0.30', '2.0') 41
('0.30', '1.9') 25
('0.30', '2.2') 40
('0.34', '2.0') 40
('0.30', '2.1') 39
('0.34', '1.9') 38
```

Note that the results are not in order since we hashed our data.

Comment: a collections.defaultdict would be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some of your other questions I see you use R. You might be interested in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), a Python Data Analysis Library, which has some similarities to R.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['0.30', '1.9',  5],['0.30', '1.9', 33],['0.30', '1.9', 39]
                  ,['0.30', '2.0', 21],['0.30', '2.0', 51],['0.30', '2.0', 51]
                  ,['0.30', '2.1', 42],['0.30', '2.1', 34],['0.30', '2.1', 43]
                  ,['0.30', '2.2', 38],['0.30', '2.2', 34],['0.30', '2.2', 50]
                  ,['0.34', '1.9', 29],['0.34', '1.9', 47],['0.34', '2.0', 45]
                  ,['0.34', '2.0', 31],['0.34', '2.0', 45],['0.34', '2.0', 57]
                  ,['0.34', '2.0', 25]])

df.groupby([0,1]).agg(lambda x: x.mean()).reset_index()
```

Produces:

```
      0    1          2
0  0.30  1.9  25.666667
1  0.30  2.0  41.000000
2  0.30  2.1  39.666667
3  0.30  2.2  40.666667
4  0.34  1.9  38.000000
5  0.34  2.0  40.600000
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative answer you can do it with `zip` in a list comprehension :

```
>>> l
[['0.30', '1.9', 5], ['0.30', '1.9', 33], ['0.30', '1.9', 39], ['0.30', '2.0', 21], ['0.30', '2.0', 51], ['0.30', '2.0', 51], ['0.30', '2.1', 42], ['0.30', '2.1', 34], ['0.30', '2.1', 43], ['0.30', '2.2', 38], ['0.30', '2.2', 34], ['0.30', '2.2', 50], ['0.34', '1.9', 29], ['0.34', '1.9', 47], ['0.34', '2.0', 45], ['0.34', '2.0', 31], ['0.34', '2.0', 45], ['0.34', '2.0', 57], ['0.34', '2.0', 25]]

>>> gl=[list(g) for k,g in groupby(l,lambda x : x[:2])]
>>> [[zip(*i)[0][0],zip(*i)[1][0],sum(zip(*i)[2])/len(i)] for i in gl]
[['0.30', '1.9', 25], ['0.30', '2.0', 41], ['0.30', '2.1', 39], ['0.30', '2.2', 40], ['0.34', '1.9', 38], ['0.34', '2.0', 40]]
```